# What's the difference between "wipe" and "wiped at"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Example sentence:

> Maria wiped (at) her purple cheek powder. It didn't come out.

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways give the same information and have the same meaning, as in this example:

1. **She smiled and wiped (at) a tear that was threatening to trail down her cheek.**

In the example 1 "at" is pointing to the "tear", the only preposition used to give a location in the phrase.

2. **I was sitting in the hospital room when Walter Cronkite made the announcement and wiped a tear from his eye.**

Now in this example it would sound strange to use "wiped at", as the preposition "from" is already being used to point a location, the eye.

So I'd just be careful about the second example, check if a preposition pointing a place is already being used in the clause, in this case don't use **wiped at**.

If you want more examples you can find them here: [Concordander](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/)